# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words' in python gensim module

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

While training using `doc2vec`, I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'words' in python gensim module
```

This is my code:

```
# Extracting titles from csv to list
with open(query+'_titles.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    titlelist = list(reader)
# build
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(size=30, window=1, alpha=0.01, min_count=2, sample=1e-5, workers=100)
model.build_vocab(titlelist)
titlearray = np.asarray(titlelist)
print 'Training Model...'
```

I use python *2.7.11* and gensim version is *3.2.0* if that helps. There must be something I am really missing.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: https://medium.com/@gofortargets/doc2vec-word2vec-in-gensim-c9321c780079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Doc2Vec` requires not just the list of sentences, but the list of *tagged* sentences. From [this discussion on DS.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10216/18375):

> In `word2vec` there is no need to label the words, because every word
>   has their own semantic meaning in the vocabulary. But in case of
>   `doc2vec`, there is a need to specify that how many number of words or
>   sentences convey a semantic meaning, so that the algorithm could
>   identify it as a single entity. For this reason, we are specifying
>   labels or tags to sentence or paragraph depending on the level of
>   semantic meaning conveyed.

Consequently, Gensim expects the following input:

```
sentences = [doc2vec.TaggedDocument(sentence, 'tag') for sentence in titlelist]
model.build_vocab(sentences)
```

Obviously, you might want to set different tags depending on the sentences to get meaningful vectors. By the way, are you sure you want to read CSV in binary mode?

Comment: Not necessarily in binary mode. Ok, I need to read contents from a file anyhow and set tags for the sentences (lines in file). But do you mean a tag for each line? What about if I have lines having sentences that are similar?

Comment: "typical practice (which will also be most memory-efficient) is for the tags list to include a unique integer id as the only tag" - https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument